# React component event handler can't find this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on some (supposedly) slight refactor work on a few React components. One has stopped working as expected for some reason–other questions asked on the web are similar but not enough to solve my scenario it seems.

I have this component, conditionally rendered from a parent:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ArrowButton extends React.Component {

    handleMove() {
        let $arrow = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        let $banner = $arrow.parents('.hero-banner');
        let bannerBottom = $banner.offset().top + $banner.outerHeight();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: bannerBottom
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="arrow-button" onClick={this.handleMove.bind(this)}>
                <div className="arrow-button__arrow"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ArrowButton;
```

Its parent places it within itself like so:

```
displayArrowButton() {
    if (this.props.showArrow) {
        return <ArrowButton />;
    }
}
...
{this.displayArrowButton()}
```

The problem: clicking the button with the bound event handler (as works elsewhere) results in a strange error that I can't help but think is a red herring:

```
Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.0.2.0.0.1`. If you're seeing this message, it probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At this time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
```

If I remove the .bind, I have no scope for this at all. I thought it might be wrong (as in window or something) but seems undefined.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

I can't find any weird reference where we have included React twice. Are there (un)common gotchas I should double check? Why would other components with the same setup, except handler body, work?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` and bundle config eg `webpack.config.js`? I've found whenever that error appears - it does mean I have 2 copies of react loaded for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got around this by simply referencing event object and target. It achieves the same result (getting to the DOM node and wrapping it with jQuery), but doesn't feel quite 'the React way'. That being said neither does the animate() method but complicating things further for no real reason than conformity isn't necessary either.

```
handleMove(e) {
    let $arrow = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(e.target));
```